# How can i implement structure array like matlab in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab

How can i implement  structure array like matlab in python ?

matlab code :

```
cluster.c=[]
cluster.indiv=[]
```

Comment: For the people not as accustomed to matlab or misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve, maybe consider expanding on what you expect the code to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do this in Python (as I explain below), it might not be the best or most pythonic approach. For other users that have to look at your code (including yourself in 3 months) this syntax is extremely confusing. Think for example about how this deals with name conflicts, undefined values and iterating over properties.

Instead consider storing the data in a data structure that is better suited for this such as a [dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm). Then you can just store everything in

```
cluster = {'c':[],'indiv':[]}
```

---

**Imitating Matlab in a bad way**:

You can assign properties to any mutable objects in python.
If you need an object just for data storage, then you can define a custom class without any functionality in the following way:

```
class CustomStruct():
    pass
```

Then you can have

```
struct=CustomStruct()
struct.c=[]
```

and change or request properties of the class in this way.

**Better approach:**

If you really want to store these things as properties of an object, then it might be best to define the variables in the init of that class.

```
class BetterStruct():
    def __init__(self):
        self.c=[]
        self.indiv=[]
```

In this way, users looking at your code can immediately understand the expected values, and you can guarantee that they are initalised in a proper fashion.

**Allowing data control**

If you want to verify the data when it is stored, or if it has to be calculated once the user requests it (instead of storing it constantly), then consider using [Python property decorators](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)